# How to best publish files to multiple sftp targets

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-integration, jsch

I have the following `sftp` bean Id configured in my spring `application-context` file. It defines two sftp targets which my application is to send different types of files to:

```
<bean id="targetA" 

class="com.sftp.Sender">
        <constructor-arg value="${A.host}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${A.username}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${A.remoteDir}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${A.notificationDir}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="targetB" class="com.sftp.Sender">
        <constructor-arg value="${B.host}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${B.username}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${B.remoteDir}"/>
    </bean>
```

My `main` class looks something like this:

```
public class Main {

    Occ occ= ctx.getBean("occ", Occ.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            if (args != null && args.length >= 1) {
                String target = args[0];
                occ.rePublish(target);

            } else {
                    String target = "Both";
                   orc.processReports(target);

                } 
}
```

My `Occ` class something like this:

```
public class Occ {

                 public void rePublish(String target) {
                     processReports(target);
                }

                public void processReports(String target) {
                    // determines who the target is and prepare the appropriate 
                    // file to send to that target

                    if (target.equal("Both")) {
                        // prepare both target A and B files 
                    }
                }

            }
```

Generally, when the program is executed, it should prepare both sets of files for both target A and target B. In certain scenarios, one transfer may fail and I want to be able to prepare and distribute files for just that target. I can only think of passing in the resend target as `arguments` in `main` method. But is this the best way to do this? What are your thoughts and how would you do it? Can I restructure the above code in other better ways?